# SpringBoot with Swagger for a multipart/form-data, show all enum possible values

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

For a SpringBoot project I defined a multipart/form-data API.

I configured the Swagger for this.

As parameter I'm using an Enum.

Is it possible to show the possible values about this enum into my Swagger?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try with the `@ApiModel` and `@ApiModelProperty` annotations?

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
@ApiModel
public class Employee {
  @ApiModelProperty
  public Role role;
  // standard setters and getters
}

@ApiModel
public enum Role {
   Engineer, Clerk, Driver, Janitor;
}
```

Regards